# How to force cmake to link a dynamic lib?

Tags: c++, cmake, environment-variables, lib

**I am cross-compiling a camera driver. The driver uses cmake to create makefile, I have set the environment variables ,but when the makefile do the linking it still link the default lib, which won't work. Why the ld won't search other directories? I can't find nowhere to set the right path. Below is what i got：**
[image]

**The cmakelists.txt is like this:**

```
if(WIN32)
    cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)
else(UNIX)
    cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
endif(WIN32)


project (MoveSenseCamera)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

message ("cxx Flags: " ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})

add_subdirectory (MoveSenseCamera)
add_subdirectory (Samples)

if(WIN32)
    install(FILES
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/README.md
        DESTINATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Release/MoveSenseSDK-Windows)
else(UNIX)
    install(FILES 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/.gitignore
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/README.md
        DESTINATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Release/MoveSenseSDK-Linux)
endif(WIN32)

message("Done! \n")
```

**My toolChain.cmake is like this:**

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /home/d01/cross/arm-hisiv300-linux/target)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /home/d01/cross/arm-hisiv300-linux/target)
set(CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX /home/d01/P_doubleeye/MoveSenseSDK1.2.7/build/bin)
set(tools /home/d01/cross/arm-hisiv300-linux/bin)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${tools}/arm-hisiv300-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${tools}/arm-hisiv300-linux-uclibcgnueabi-g++)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

**Generated makefile:**

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.10

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all

.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:


#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:


# Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list


# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:


# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:

.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/bin/cmake

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /usr/bin/cmake -E remove -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = "/home/d01/P_doubleeye/MoveSenseSDK-Linux-CSx-1.2.7-(no opencv)"

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = "/home/d01/P_doubleeye/MoveSenseSDK-Linux-CSx-1.2.7-(no opencv)/build"

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target install/strip
install/strip: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Installing the project stripped..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_DO_STRIP=1 -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/strip

# Special rule for the target install/strip
install/strip/fast: preinstall/fast
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Installing the project stripped..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_DO_STRIP=1 -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/strip/fast

# Special rule for the target install
install: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Install the project..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install

# Special rule for the target install
install/fast: preinstall/fast
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Install the project..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/fast

# Special rule for the target install/local
install/local: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Installing only the local directory..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LOCAL_ONLY=1 -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/local

# Special rule for the target install/local
install/local/fast: preinstall/fast
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Installing only the local directory..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LOCAL_ONLY=1 -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/local/fast

# Special rule for the target list_install_components
list_install_components:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Available install components are: \"Unspecified\" \"dev\""
.PHONY : list_install_components

# Special rule for the target list_install_components
list_install_components/fast: list_install_components

.PHONY : list_install_components/fast

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "No interactive CMake dialog available..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -E echo No\ interactive\ CMake\ dialog\ available.
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache

.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache

.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start "/home/d01/P_doubleeye/MoveSenseSDK-Linux-CSx-1.2.7-(no opencv)/build/CMakeFiles" "/home/d01/P_doubleeye/MoveSenseSDK-Linux-CSx-1.2.7-(no opencv)/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks"
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start "/home/d01/P_doubleeye/MoveSenseSDK-Linux-CSx-1.2.7-(no opencv)/build/CMakeFiles" 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean

.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named MoveSenseCamera

# Build rule for target.
MoveSenseCamera: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 MoveSenseCamera
.PHONY : MoveSenseCamera

# fast build rule for target.
MoveSenseCamera/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f MoveSenseCamera/CMakeFiles/MoveSenseCamera.dir/build.make MoveSenseCamera/CMakeFiles/MoveSenseCamera.dir/build
.PHONY : MoveSenseCamera/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named ImageCapture

# Build rule for target.
ImageCapture: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ImageCapture
.PHONY : ImageCapture

# fast build rule for target.
ImageCapture/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f Samples/CMakeFiles/ImageCapture.dir/build.make Samples/CMakeFiles/ImageCapture.dir/build
.PHONY : ImageCapture/fast

# Help Target
help:
    @echo "The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:"
    @echo "... all (the default if no target is provided)"
    @echo "... clean"
    @echo "... depend"
    @echo "... install/strip"
    @echo "... install"
    @echo "... install/local"
    @echo "... list_install_components"
    @echo "... edit_cache"
    @echo "... rebuild_cache"
    @echo "... MoveSenseCamera"
    @echo "... ImageCapture"
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

**Generated CMakeCache.txt:**

```
# This is the CMakeCache file.
# For build in directory: /home/d01/P_doubleeye/MoveSenseSDK-Linux-CSx-1.2.7-(no opencv)/build
# It was generated by CMake: /usr/bin/cmake
# You can edit this file to change values found and used by cmake.
# If you do not want to change any of the values, simply exit the editor.
# If you do want to change a value, simply edit, save, and exit the editor.
# The syntax for the file is as follows:
# KEY:TYPE=VALUE
# KEY is the name of a variable in the cache.
# TYPE is a hint to GUIs for the type of VALUE, DO NOT EDIT TYPE!.
# VALUE is the current value for the KEY.

########################
# EXTERNAL cache entries
########################

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_AR:FILEPATH=/home/d01/cross/arm-hisiv300-linux/bin/arm-hisiv300-linux-uclibcgnueabi-ar

//Choose the type of build, options are: None(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS or
// CMAKE_C_FLAGS used) Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel.
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=

//Enable/Disable color output during build.
CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON

//A wrapper around 'ar' adding the appropriate '--plugin' option
// for the GCC compiler
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_AR:FILEPATH=/home/d01/cross/arm-hisiv300-linux/bin/arm-hisiv300-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc-ar

//A wrapper around 'ranlib' adding the appropriate '--plugin' option
// for the GCC compiler
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_RANLIB:FILEPATH=/home/d01/cross/arm-hisiv300-linux/bin/arm-hisiv300-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc-ranlib

//Flags used by the compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the compiler during debug builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds for minimum
// size.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds with debug info.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG

//A wrapper around 'ar' adding the appropriate '--plugin' option
// for the GCC compiler
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_AR:FILEPATH=/home/d01/cross/arm-hisiv300-linux/bin/arm-hisiv300-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc-ar

//A wrapper around 'ranlib' adding the appropriate '--plugin' option
// for the GCC compiler
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_RANLIB:FILEPATH=/home/d01/cross/arm-hisiv300-linux/bin/arm-hisiv300-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc-ranlib

//Flags used by the compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the compiler during debug builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds for minimum
// size.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds with debug info.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the linker.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during debug builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release minsize builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during Release with Debug Info builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Enable/Disable output of compile commands during generation.
CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=OFF

//Install path prefix, prepended onto install directories.
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_LINKER:FILEPATH=/home/d01/cross/arm-hisiv300-linux/bin/arm-hisiv300-linux-uclibcgnueabi-ld

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/make

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during debug builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release minsize builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during Release with Debug Info builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_NM:FILEPATH=/home/d01/cross/arm-hisiv300-linux/bin/arm-hisiv300-linux-uclibcgnueabi-nm

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_OBJCOPY:FILEPATH=/home/d01/cross/arm-hisiv300-linux/bin/arm-hisiv300-linux-uclibcgnueabi-objcopy

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_OBJDUMP:FILEPATH=/home/d01/cross/arm-hisiv300-linux/bin/arm-hisiv300-linux-uclibcgnueabi-objdump

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME:STATIC=MoveSenseCamera

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_RANLIB:FILEPATH=/home/d01/cross/arm-hisiv300-linux/bin/arm-hisiv300-linux-uclibcgnueabi-ranlib

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of dll's.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during debug builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release minsize builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during Release with Debug Info builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//If set, runtime paths are not added when installing shared libraries,
// but are added when building.
CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH:BOOL=NO

//If set, runtime paths are not added when using shared libraries.
CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH:BOOL=NO

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during debug builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release minsize builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during Release with Debug Info builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_STRIP:FILEPATH=/home/d01/cross/arm-hisiv300-linux/bin/arm-hisiv300-linux-uclibcgnueabi-strip

//The CMake toolchain file
CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH=/home/d01/P_doubleeye/MoveSenseSDK-Linux-CSx-1.2.7-(no opencv)/toolChain.cmake

//If this value is on, makefiles will be generated without the
// .SILENT directive, and all commands will be echoed to the console
// during the make.  This is useful for debugging only. With Visual
// Studio IDE projects all commands are done without /nologo.
CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=FALSE

//Value Computed by CMake
MoveSenseCamera_BINARY_DIR:STATIC=/home/d01/P_doubleeye/MoveSenseSDK-Linux-CSx-1.2.7-(no opencv)/build

//Dependencies for the target
MoveSenseCamera_LIB_DEPENDS:STATIC=general;udev;

//Value Computed by CMake
MoveSenseCamera_SOURCE_DIR:STATIC=/home/d01/P_doubleeye/MoveSenseSDK-Linux-CSx-1.2.7-(no opencv)


########################
# INTERNAL cache entries
########################

//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_AR
CMAKE_AR-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//This is the directory where this CMakeCache.txt was created
CMAKE_CACHEFILE_DIR:INTERNAL=/home/d01/P_doubleeye/MoveSenseSDK-Linux-CSx-1.2.7-(no opencv)/build
//Major version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_MAJOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=3
//Minor version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_MINOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=10
//Patch version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_PATCH_VERSION:INTERNAL=2
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE
CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Path to CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND:INTERNAL=/usr/bin/cmake
//Path to cpack program executable.
CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND:INTERNAL=/usr/bin/cpack
//Path to ctest program executable.
CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND:INTERNAL=/usr/bin/ctest
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_AR
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_AR-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_RANLIB
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_RANLIB-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_COMPILER_AR
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_AR-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_COMPILER_RANLIB
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_RANLIB-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS
CMAKE_C_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Executable file format
CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_FORMAT:INTERNAL=ELF
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS
CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Name of external makefile project generator.
CMAKE_EXTRA_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator.
CMAKE_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=Unix Makefiles
//Name of generator platform.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator toolset.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET:INTERNAL=
//Source directory with the top level CMakeLists.txt file for this
// project
CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY:INTERNAL=/home/d01/P_doubleeye/MoveSenseSDK-Linux-CSx-1.2.7-(no opencv)
//Install .so files without execute permission.
CMAKE_INSTALL_SO_NO_EXE:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_LINKER
CMAKE_LINKER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_NM
CMAKE_NM-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//number of local generators
CMAKE_NUMBER_OF_MAKEFILES:INTERNAL=3
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_OBJCOPY
CMAKE_OBJCOPY-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_OBJDUMP
CMAKE_OBJDUMP-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Platform information initialized
CMAKE_PLATFORM_INFO_INITIALIZED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RANLIB
CMAKE_RANLIB-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Path to CMake installation.
CMAKE_ROOT:INTERNAL=/usr/share/cmake-3.10
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH
CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH
CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STRIP
CMAKE_STRIP-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//uname command
CMAKE_UNAME:INTERNAL=/bin/uname
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE
CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved！ I spend some time to learn about cmake. I found the cmakelists.txt to generate libmovesensecamera.so is not correct. I change this line:

```
link_directories("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
```

to this:

```
link_directories("/home/d01/cross/arm-hisiv300-linux/target/lib")
```

So, this is a bug which cause the environment-variables to fail on that step. I only temporarily solve it.